# Passing test or passed test?

Tags: past-participles, present-participles

In [this video](https://youtu.be/CTuTVKNYrdw?t=1822), he says "Now, we have two **passing tests**." It doesn't make sense to me by saying **passing test**. I would say **passed test** instead. Because a test can only **be passed**, right? How could a test pass itself?

Answer (score 2):

Shortly before that moment in the video, the speaker refers to "a failing test", and it is clear that he means "a test that was failed", that is, a test whose condition was not met in the code.
When he mentions "two passing tests", the window at the left of the screen labeled "Test Explorer" shows the header "Passed Tests", and the names of two tests whose conditions were met.

From the perspective of the code, on each run, the tests were failed or passed, but from the perspective of the person debugging the code, it seems reasonable to use the present participle as an adjective, since the tests will be passed each time the debugger executes them.

In any case, it's clear what he meant by the term "passing tests".

Comment: That phrasing also comes up in the context of continuous integration, in which the tests may be, at the moment, either passing or failing.

Comment: @Ryan M I don't understand your explanation, if a test is being checked, no one would know whether it's going to pass or not. So, is it passing or failing?

Comment: Since continuous integration runs on an ongoing basis, the test is either broken ("failing") or not broken ("passing") at any point in time.  Since it's an ongoing thing, the present participle tends to be used.